# Usercontrol in EditItemTemplate of templated control. How to achieve two-way databinding?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I was hoping to replace the EditItemTemplate of an ASP.NET ListView with a user control but I can't work out how to bind it to the data item in the ListView to achieve two-way data binding. The data item isn't a simple property. It's an object.
This seems only to give one-way Eval type databinding:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <uc:MyUserControl id="thecontrol" runat="server" TheObject='<%# Container.DataItem %>'/>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

This gives an error:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <uc:MyUserControl id="thecontrol" runat="server" TheObject='<%# Bind("Container.DataItem") %>'/>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

As does this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <uc:MyUserControl id="thecontrol" runat="server" TheObject='<%# Bind("this") %>'/>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Is there some binding expression syntax to give two-way databinding to the current item in an EditItemTemplate?

Edit. This is the user control:

```
public partial class EditItemUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public TestObject TheObject
        {
            get
            {
                return new TestObject() { ID = Int32.Parse(hfID.Value), Name = txtName.Text };
            }
            set
            {
                hfID.Value = value.ID.ToString();
                txtName.Text = value.Name;
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference. I was doing it wrong. A user control lives in the context of the page where it's rendered so there's no need to set a DataSource on it. In the .ascx file you can just use:

```
Text = '<%# Bind("MyProperty") %>'
```

or

```
Text = '<%# Eval("MyProperty") %>'
```

where MyProperty is some property of the parent control's DataSource.